# Existence of elementd of infinite order in finitely generated infinite group

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

Let $G$ be a finitely generated group of infinite order.
Then is there always an element $g$ of infinite order in $G$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No: the [Grigorchuk group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grigorchuk_group) is a counterexample.